# Linkedin login screen Java Selenium can't sign out

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, linkedin-api

I created an excel with random emails and passwords in 2 coulmns and excel name is "deneme5". Selenium automatically tries all the emails but once it's logged in with the correct one it's not logging out. Plus it doesn't write the info if the test passed or failed to the excel file.

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Excel_Read_Write {

        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverWait wait;
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        XSSFSheet sheet;
        XSSFCell cell;

        public void ReadData() throws IOException {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"); //location of cromdriver exe
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
            driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login/tr"); 
            driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
            //new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
            File src= new File("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\deneme5.xlsx"); //excel sheet which i put 10 random email and password which one of them is true 
            FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(src); 
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(finput); 
            sheet= workbook.getSheetAt(0); 
            for(int i=1; i<= sheet.getLastRowNum() ; i++) {
                XSSFCell cell3 =sheet.getRow(i).createCell(3);
                //this loop for writing all the email and passwords one by one  
                System.out.print("Sena");
                cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0); 
                cell .setCellType(CellType.STRING); 
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue()); 
                cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1); 
                cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
                driver.findElement(By.className("btn__primary--large")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
                String actualUrl="https://www.linkedin.com/feed/"; 
                String expectedUrl= driver.getCurrentUrl();
                if(actualUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedUrl)) {
                    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                    cell3.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                    cell3.setCellValue("test passed");
                    driver.findElement(By.id("ember19")).click();
                    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
                    
                    
                    }
                else {  cell3.setCellValue("test failed");
                    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
                    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();

                }}

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Desktop\\deneme5.xlsx");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Thread Sleep after launching browser.
Also replace last two lines of your code with below lines.

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//button[contains(@id, 'ember')]")).click();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign Out")).click();
```

Comment: Thread Sleep is not working

Comment: First Xpath is also change. I have made it as dynamic